# Generate a random string based on a regular expression

Tags: javascript

Is there any way of generating random text which satisfies provided regular expression.
I am looking for a function which works like below

```
var reg = Some Regular Expression  
var str = RandString(reg)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have seen fairly good solutions in [perl](https://github.com/bowman/Regexp-Genex) and [ruby](https://github.com/benburkert/randexp) on github, but I think there are technical issues that make a complete solution impossible. For example, /[0-9]+/ has an infinite upper bound, which is not practical for selecting random numbers from.

Never seen it in JavaScript, but you could translate.

---

EDIT: After googling for a few seconds...
https://github.com/fent/randexp.js

Comment: Very useful answer and matches my requirement exactly.

Answer (score 1):

if you know what the regular expression is, you can just generate random strings, then use a function that references the index of the letters and changes them as needed. Regex expressions vary widely, so it will be difficult to find one in particular that satisfies all possible regex.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is pretty open so hopefully this steers you to the right solution. Get the current time (in seconds), MD5 it, check it against a REGEX, return the match.

Running Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MattLo/3gKrb/

Usage: `RandString(/([A-Za-z])/ig); // expected to be a string`

Comment: Very useful answer and closely related to my requirement.

Comment: The fiddle gives wrong out put.. Eg: `/a/ig` gives me `aaa` and `aaaa` as output when it should just be `a`. Tested with many other regex inputs and it breaks

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript, the following modules can generate a random match to a regex:

- [pxeger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pxeger)
- [randexp.js](https://fent.github.io/randexp.js/)
- [regexgen](https://github.com/arh23/regexgen)

Comment: To generate *all* matches of a regex, you can also use [genex.js](https://github.com/alixaxel/genex.js).